# Socket.io Basic web socket connection with url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

My client is making a WebSocket request to this URL: `ws://localhost:3000/feed/XBTMUR`

[image]

In my server, I have NodeJs running express. I want to use Socket.io to listen to clients connecting to this URL and send feed data regularly.
I tried this but it is not working:

```
var app = require('../app');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);
/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

var io  = require('socket.io')(server);
var feed =
    io.of('/feed/XBTMUR').on('connection', function (socket) {

        socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
        socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected, id ' + socket.id);
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('a user disconnected, id '  + socket.id);
    })
})
setInterval(()=>{
    io.sockets.emit('this', { receivers: 'everyone'});
},1000)

server.listen(port);
```

The client is not using Socket io.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to not use socket io client side if you use it server side. Why do you use it server side by the way ?

Comment: I cannot control the client. I solved it using npm ws  library instead

Comment: This library is a very good choice :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel the the implementation is wrong while reading the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-name).

```
var feed = io.of('/feed')     // `/feed` is the namespace
.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.to('XBTMUR', { hello: 'world' });  // `XBTMUR` is the room / socket id

});
```

Hope this helps.